# Django Linking a html page to a view

Tags: django

So I know that there are other people who have asked the same question, and I have read through them. However, the solutions provided there are giving me a strange error, and I would appreciate any help in understanding it.

So here's my home.html file:

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <!-- <a href="/home/signup">Sign Up</a> -->
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
</body>
```

And here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

def signup(request):
    return render(request, "signup.html")
```

And here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import home, signup

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/', signup, name="signup"),
    url(r'^', home, name="home"),
]
```

Thank you for all the help :)

Edit:
The error message is

```
Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Also I actually changed the way I did urls.py. Now, I only have one urls.py in my main mysite folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from home import views
from accounts import views as accountsViews

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^home/', views.home),
    url(r'^signup', accountsViews.signup),
]
```

Comment: You say you get a strange error - what error is that?

Comment: post your another urls

Comment: Sorry @solarissmoke @"Mauricio Cortazar" I forgot to mention those. I have just added a new edit.

Comment: The second set of urls you have posted have no `name`, so there is no way for the URL template tag to find them by name.

Comment: Aha it works now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second url in 'urls.py' does not have a name.

The url tags would not be able to find them by name --  '{% url 'signup' %}'

Comment: Hope this helps